# Is it possible to switch from speaker mode in Agora Video SDK of Flutter?

Tags: flutter, agora.io

By default, it is a video call, so you talk on the speaker. Is it possible to hear the sound with ears like a normal call with video sdk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got an answer from Agora.io.
We can use some APIs to enable earphone mode.

> you could use one of the APIs, "setEnableSpeakerphone", "disableVideo" or "muteLocalVideoStream"